# Make the file download manager window the front window in Firefox/Safari

Tags: firefox, safari, download

If Safari/Firefox have already downloaded files then they keep a download manager window open. When the user downloads a new file from my site, is there any way to force that download manager window to the front of all windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. The Download manager is not under the site's control. Maybe through a Firefox extension, but definitely not using normal JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you make the download window close on completion?  Then it will re-open each time, which usually results in it being on top.

Comment: How do I make it close on completion? If I can do that, I assume I should be able to make it the focus/front window.

Comment: I think the OP is talking about how to do this programmatically, from the site's end.

Comment: Yea that's what I don't get - how can the site close the download window?

Comment: That;s how I understood the question -- get the site to close it programmatically.  I don't know of any way to do that, but I was suggesting that if FFX can ALWAYS close the download window, then won't it always have to OPEN it new each time, putting it on top?

Comment: Sorry -- forgot to say that under about:config there is an option called browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting and browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone.  I think those will do what you want.